# Alert user in browser of activity in separate tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, silverlight, signalr

We are using a Silverlight application together with a third party dashboard tool, both running in separate tabs.
When we click in the dashboard we use SignalR to communicate with the Silverlight application.

Whenever this happens, we want to highlight the tab of the Silverlight application, however we do not want to use an alert box because this requires the user to do an extra click.

Is there a way we can trigger an alert box in the Silverlight application (or html page it is running in) to do an alert that disappears after x seconds?

Either we want a focus on the tab of the Silverlight application (however this is browser blocked) or have a tab highlight which, besides clicking the tab, does not require any user interaction.

The application is browser independent.

Comment: Desktop Notifications? http://girliemac.com/html5-notifications-webOS-style/ (Not for IE)

Comment: Our application has to support multiple browser, including IE, so this is sadly enough not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a child window that pops up and will close after a certain amount of time. You can make it look like an alert if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution that attracts the user's attention like web basted applications as Google Talk and Facebook Chat? They change the title on interval basis.

In my opinion you won't find any other, better, cross-browser solution at this moment.

You could hook a dedicated piece of javscript to a SignalR hub on every page you'd like. As soon as you focus on the tab you'll stop flashing.

[Here](http://heyman.info/2010/sep/30/jquery-title-alert/) you'll find a jQuery plugin that does what I just suggested